# Powershell Service Status || HTML Output

Tags: html, powershell, window

I have a below code which will check common services status for all servers and some services will be checked as per the server list.
IF it is a app server , it will check specific list of server and if it is a db server it will check specific list of services.

Below code is working fine and i am getting output in console. I am only facing issue to get this in html table and i want the result as bellow:

```
Common Service Check
ServerA service1 running 
ServerA service2 running 
Serverx service1 running 
Servery service2 running 


Application Status

ServerA service3 running 
ServerA service4 running 

DB Server Status
Serverx service5 running 
Servery service6 running
```

Below is the code:

```
$server = Import-Csv "\path\server.txt"
foreach($ServerName in $server)
{
    $IDE = $($ServerName.types)  
    $hostname = $($ServerName.sname) 

    $CService = @('service1*'
        'service2')

    foreach($commonser in $CService)
    {
        $servicecomm = Get-Service "$commonser" -ComputerName $hostname
        write-host $servicecomm.MachineName $servicecomm.name $servicecomm.Status 
    }
    #write-host $IDE
    #write-host $hostname

    If ($IDE -eq "APP")
    {

    $APPList = @(
        'Service3'
        'Service4*'
    )

    foreach($appslist in $APPList)
    {
        $serviceapp = Get-Service "$appslist" -ComputerName $hostname
        Write-Host  $serviceapp.MachineName $serviceapp.name $serviceapp.Status 
    }
}
elseif($IDE -eq "DB")
{
    $DBList = @(
        'service5'
        'service6'
    )
    foreach($dblist in $DBList)
    {
        $servicedb = Get-Service "$dblist" -ComputerName $hostname
        Write-Host  $servicedb.MachineName $servicedb.name $servicedb.Status 
    }
}
```

Below text file of server list

```
types,sname
APP,ServerA
APP,ServerB
DB,ServerX
DB,ServerY
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you will need to design `HTML` formatted page that will fit your needs. Here is a brief example of how to **build** `HTML` page with script you have. Like so:

```
$HTML = '<html>
<body>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;    
}
</style>
</head>'
$HTML_CommonServiceCheck = '<table><tr><th>Common Service Check</th></tr>'
$HTML_ApplicationStatus = '<table><tr><th>Application Status</th></tr>'
$HTML_DBServerStatus = '<table><tr><th>DB Server Status</th></tr>'

$server = @(Import-Csv '\path\server.txt')

foreach($ServerName in $server)
{
    $IDE = $($ServerName.types)  
    $hostname = $($ServerName.sname) 

    $CService = @('service1','service2')

    foreach($commonser in $CService)
    {
        $servicecomm = Get-Service $commonser -ComputerName $hostname
        $HTML_CommonServiceCheck += '<tr><td>{0} {1} {2}</td></tr>' -f $servicecomm.MachineName, $servicecomm.name, $servicecomm.Status 
    }

    If ($IDE -eq "APP")
    {

        $APPList = @('service3','service4*')

        foreach($appslist in $APPList)
        {
            $serviceapp = Get-Service $appslist -ComputerName $hostname
            $HTML_ApplicationStatus += '<tr><td>{0} {1} {2}</td></tr>' -f $serviceapp.MachineName, $serviceapp.name, $serviceapp.Status 
        }

    }
    elseif($IDE -eq "DB")
    {
        $DBList = @('service5','service6')

        foreach($dblist in $DBList)
        {
            $servicedb = Get-Service $dblist -ComputerName $hostname
            $HTML_DBServerStatus += '<tr><td>{0} {1} {2}</td></tr>' -f $servicedb.MachineName, $servicedb.name, $servicedb.Status 
        }

    }
}

$HTML_CommonServiceCheck += '</table>'
$HTML_ApplicationStatus += '</table>'
$HTML_DBServerStatus += '</table>'
$HTML += $HTML_CommonServiceCheck
$HTML += $HTML_ApplicationStatus
$HTML += $HTML_DBServerStatus
$HTML += '</body></html>'
```

Answer (score 1):

To start, you will need to collect the results, not just output them to screen as they are returned like you are now. I'll get to that in a second though. First let's take a quick look at `Get-Service`. If you run `Get-Help Get-Service` you'll see a parameter set with the syntax of:

```
Get-Service [[-Name] <String[]>] [-ComputerName <String[]>] [-DependentServices] [-Exclude <String[]>] [-Include <String[]>] [-RequiredServices] [<CommonParameters>]
```

Now what that tells me is that the `-Name` parameter takes an array of strings (as indicated by `<String[]>`, since if it only accepted a single string it would be listed as `<String>`). It also accepts an array of string for the `-ComputerName` parameter. This means that we can run the command once per category, so just 3 times, which should speed things up. Past that we can output the results into HTML fragments, and then combine those fragments into one HTML page that we can output to file and open in a web browser.

So first we get the data from the servers:

```
$server = Import-Csv "\path\server.txt"

$CService = @('service1*','service2')
$APPList = @('Service3','Service4*')
$DBList = @('service5','service6')

$CServiceResults = Get-Service $CService -ComputerName $server.sname
$APPListResults = Get-Service $APPList -ComputerName $server.sname
$DBListResults = Get-Service $DBList -ComputerName $server.sname
```

Now that we have the data we can create HTML fragments for each table, including a title for each. We have to convert the output to a string, so that we can merge them all later:

```
$CServiceFrag = $CServiceResults | ConvertTo-Html -Property MachineName,ServiceName,Status -As Table -Pre "<H2>Common Services</H2>" -Fragment | Out-String
$APPListFrag = $APPListResults | ConvertTo-Html -Property MachineName,ServiceName,Status -As Table -Pre "<H2>App Services</H2>" -Fragment | Out-String
$DBListFrag = $DBListResults | ConvertTo-Html -Property MachineName,ServiceName,Status -As Table -Pre "<H2>DB Services</H2>" -Fragment | Out-String
```

We should add a little formatting to make the tables look nice, so the report isn't a complete eyesore.

```
$Header = @"
<style>
H1, H2 {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

table {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 8px;
}

table tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}

table tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

table th {
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #3366FF;
    color: white;
}
</style>
"@
```

Then we put it all together with `ConvertTo-HTML` and output it to a file. Once we have the file we just use `Invoke-Item` to open it in the default browser.

```
ConvertTo-Html -Head $Header -Pre "<H1>Service Status Report</H1>" -PostContent $CServiceFrag,$APPListFrag,$DBListFrag|Set-Content C:\Temp\Services.htm
Invoke-Item C:\temp\Services.htm
```

Sample output:
[image: Sample Report]

Note that my HTML skills are trash, so the style info was almost straight ripped off from https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp, with a little guessing and modifications by me to suite the need.

**Edit:** I can't help with setting colors, but I can help with sorting if you don't mind doing that before you output to the web page. For that you would modify the lines that create your HTML fragments. For example, if you want to sort the common services by server name you could do:

```
$CServiceFrag = $CServiceResults | Sort MachineName | ConvertTo-Html -Property MachineName,ServiceName,Status -As Table -Pre "<H2>Common Services</H2>" -Fragment | Out-String
```

If you wanted it sorted by service name you would change `Sort MachineName` to `Sort ServiceName`.

Comment: Thanks Mate :) . This really helps alot. Can you tell me how i can add color here if the service is in **stopped** state and also if i want to sort by machine name or service name?